# Is $\int_0^{\pi}\log \sin \theta d\theta$ not well-defined?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Is $\int_0^{\pi}\log \sin \theta d\theta$ not well-defined?

On the third edition of Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, page 160 it states: As a final example we compute the special integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\pi}\log \sin \theta d\theta.
\end{equation*}
...

The same proof applies near the vertex $\pi$, and we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\pi}\log (-2ie^{ix}\sin x)dx=0.
\end{equation*}

Here are my questions.

(i) I think $\int_0^{\pi}\log \sin \theta d\theta$ is not well defined, since $\log \sin\theta$ is undefined when $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$.

(ii) Actually, I think we only obtain something like
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0+\delta}^{\pi-\delta}\log (-2ie^{ix}\sin x)dx=0.
\end{equation*}
Why is $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0+\delta}^{\pi-\delta}\log (-2ie^{ix}\sin x)dx=\int_0^{\pi}\log (-2ie^{ix}\sin x)dx=0$? Notice $\log (-2ie^{ix}\sin x)$ is undefined when  $x=0$ and $x=\pi$.

I show you the whole context of the questions below. I have trouble understanding the statement with the red line.
[image]

Comment: I've come across this integral in real analysis improper integrals on real line might give you some context and $\int_{0+\delta}^{\pi-\delta}=\int_0^\pi$ because we define it that way

Comment: @RandomGuy Could you recommend a textbook which covers this topic?

Comment: Any real analysis book at like undergraduate level will mostly have it its an important chapter

Answer (score 2):

As Lebesgue integral it's always well-defined because log is Lebesgue integrable on (0,1).

What's not defined is the log function on the complex plane. More precisely, the imaginary part of log will change 2pi if you draw a loop containing the origin. What the book is doing in some sense is to avoid this issue when taking contour integral.

Comment: As Lebesgue integral it's always well-defined because $log$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1)$. Which theorem is used here?

Comment: @studyhard Are you familiar with the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @MarkViola I should review it. I forget a lot. Which theorem is used here?

Comment: I think you need to look at any real analysis textbook introducing Lebesgue integration.